# Autoclicker does not activate the window

Tags: python, automation

I wanted to create an autoclicker that would "remember" current position of my mouse pointer, move to specific location on the desktop, perform a double click and then come back to where it was and will do this randomly every 1 to 4 seconds. This way I wanted to achieve an autoclick in a specific place and more or less be able to use my mouse to browse other stuff.

What I want to click is in a different window, it is a program that I leave open visible on one half of my desktop and on the other half I want to do other things. The problem is that auto clicker does not make the program an active window and the click does not work.

```
import pyautogui
import threading
import random

def makro():
    z = random.randint(1,4) #timer set to random value between 1 and 4 seconds
    (x, y) = pyautogui.position() #remember current position of mouse pointer
    threading.Timer(z, makro).start() 
    pyautogui.doubleClick(1516, 141) #perform a double click in this location (this clicks do not make the window active and clicks do not work)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y) #come back to original mouse pointer location
makro()
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Perhaps add a single click on the other window to make it the active window first? Like the way you would do it for yourself in case the window wasnt active....

Answer (score 0):

I think adding
`pyautogui.click(1516, 141)` before `pyautogui.doubleClick(1516, 141)` could activate the window.